# Shinyapps.io only loads frames, not graphs

Tags: r, shiny, flexbox, shinyapps

I have uploaded an a shiny app to the shinypps.io server but can't see the graphs. I can see the frames but no contact. Any ideas why?

[image]

It should look like:

[image]

Comment: it's difficult to say. Could you tell how you are getting the data for the plots? Might be a firewall issue. Are there any errors in your browser console?

Comment: The data is pulled in through: df<-vroom::vroom("Clean_mask_data.csv"). I've asked other folks to see if they can see the plots and they can't either. There don't appear to be any errors in the console or log. hmm

Comment: mm interesting. Is it a big dataset? You could try with a very small dataset. Did you see the [troubleshooting](https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/Troubleshooting.html) section?

Comment: It's only a few KB. The odd thing is that I have the same issue when running from Rstudio too. Sometimes it works and sometimes not. When it doesn't work, in the console it just says Loading required package: shiny

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5216 but then only shows the panels, not the graphs.

Comment: it could be something with the order of loading libraries/objects. Does it work when you add `rm(list = ls())` just before loading the libraries in your app?

Comment: That works locally and it starts every time now. But remotely it works the first time I open it after it is uploaded. If I refresh the page it only shows the panels. It's very strange because the code is so simple. Just a few plots.

Comment: ah okay. Could you give a reproducible example of the issue? I am wondering which libraries you are using